# Can Odata be used to query on multiple lists?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, odata

I've been working on issue that I need to query on 2 lists using odata.

> Sample scenario:
>
> List 1 =
>   english/_vti_bin/client.svc/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Pages')/Items
>
> List 2 =
>   spanish/_vti_bin/client.svc/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Pages')/Items

Note: I just want to retrieve these 2 lists through odata filter or any parameters available but I didn't found any solution to resolve this issue.

So for temporary resolution I just use   $.when(List 1, List 2) just to combine the two results, but is this a good practice?

Any suggestions for this issue will be helpful.

Thanks!